# Корректность null как дефолтного параметра метода и возвращаемого значения

Tags: php, рефакторинг, чистый-код

В книге Роберта Мартина есть главы, в которых он пишет

1) **Не возвращайте null**

> Я видел бесчисленное множество приложений, в которых едва ли не каждая
>   строка начиналась с проверки null. Характерный пример:

```
public void registerItem(Item item) {
    if (item != null) {
        ItemRegistry registry = persistentStore.getItemRegistry();
        if (registry != null) {
            Item existing = registry.getItem(item.getID());
            if (existing.getBillingPeriod().hasRetailOwner()) {
                existing.register(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Если ваша кодовая база содержит
>   подобный код, возможно, вы не видите в нем ничего плохого, но это не
>   так! Возвращая null, мы фактически создаем для себя лишнюю работу, а
>   для вызывающей стороны — лишние проблемы. Стоит пропустить всего одну
>   проверку null, и приложение «уходит в штопор».

2) **Не передавайте null**

> Возвращать null из методов плохо, но передавать null при вызове еще хуже. По возможности избегайте передачи null в своем коде

---

**По поводу первого пункта**: а что тогда возвращать, если, например, не нашёл нужный искомый объект? Пустой объект? Но тогда ведь все равно придется писать условие `if (!object.isEmpty())` или подобную конструкцию? Как правильно писать код и при этом не возвращать null никогда? Или всё же можно иногда? А когда можно и почему?

**По поводу второго пункта**: значит ли это, что и дефолтными параметрами в функциях/методах не стоит пользоваться null как значениями по умолчанию? Если есть метод:

```
public function test(string $name, DateTime $deadlineTime = null, int length = null) : void {}
```

И к примеру мне **не** нужен второй параметр, а третий - нужен, я же всё равно должен null указать, правильно? А если этот метод пишу именно я - то мне следует избегать таких параметров и всегда указывать какое-то дефолтное значение вместо null? Но оно же не всегда нужно, например конечный срок ($deadlineTime) неопределен.

В общем каковы правила написания кода в данных случаях?

Comment: разве дальше в книге не описано что именно использовать вместо `null`?

Comment: Есть различные подходы и пекомендации. Например, в той же Laravel, есть методы типа firstOrFail, которые выбрасывают исключение если объект не найден; в то время как метод find может вернуть null. По второму вопросу - нет, передавать второй параметр не нужно.

Comment: @Grundy ну для возврата он привел один случай в виде пустого списка (например должен был быть список строк). И это в случае когда ниже идёт цикл foreach по нему (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxTwc.png). На этом примеры исчерпались. Но со списком всё довольно понятно. А в других более "боевых" условиях что?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov По второму вопросу я видимо некорректно написал: второй параметр не нужен, а трейтий - нужен.

Comment: Обычно языки, даже PHP, учитывают такое, и не дают возможности ставить обязательный параметр после необязательного. Так что это - вопрос организации параметров в функции.

Comment: Вот ещё одна статья про  null  - [Why Null Is Bad](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/13/why-null-is-bad.html). Часто упоминается  плохой дизайн и процедурный подход в программировании, когда в коде интенсивно используются  null

Comment: @DanielProtopopov так они  **оба** не обязательные. Просто в какой-то момент мне понадобиться один из них

Comment: @Jigius так в этом и речь, если вы не заметили. В книге это также описывается, но не раскрываются все нюансы и подробности как этого корректно избегать/и что корректно надо писать. В этом мой вопрос и состоит

Comment: Одним из вариантов является использование паттерна [Null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) - есть пример на php. Но это ООП подход.

Comment: В теории самым правильным подходом является отсутствие значения null в языке вообще. Взамен нужен [Option type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type). Но это в теории...

Comment: @СергейМишин у вас слишком много неопределенности, и в PHP, да я думаю и в других языках такие подходы вряд ли бы были актуальными. Можете передавать именной массив, но в любом случае функция должна знать какой параметр подразумевается во время вызова функции и какое его значение.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov ну хорошо. вопрос: при написании своих функций/методов мне не обязательно избегать значений по умолчанию в виде null? Если да - я спокоен (относительно второго пункта), если нужно всегда, чтоб бы ли не null - то как правильно и как быть? С первым пунктом тоже интересно всё

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Null object паттерн неного походит на некий костыль, если честно, чтобы заткнуть теоретически возможно вываливающиеся ошибки. Во всяком случае в примере с php так выглядит) Но задумку примерно понимаю как использовать

Comment: @СергейМишин null я бы использовал по назначению, для объектов, для остальных типов типа DateTime или базовых передавал бы что-то действительно «по-умолчанию» такого же типа, чтобы сократить вариативность. Для объектов же, что поделаешь, придётся делать is_null проверку. Можете использовать документацию PHPDoc и аннотацию MyModel|DateTime|null.